# SQL Join to get none existing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables in SQL Server DB.  I have a dropdownmenu on my c# page where staff should be able to choose the relevant plan and it should show all users who do not have a current plan setup

Table 1 contains all users

Table 2 only contains people who have a plan.  They also can have different plan_id's in table 2 from 1-10.

I need a SQL join which returns all people who do not have a plan at all or the plan id does not match the one selected from the dropdownlist

E.G a user could exist on table 2 with 3 entries with plan_id's 2,3 and 4.

E.G If a user selects plan 7 from the downdownlist, the user would appear in the list as they currently do not have a plan matching the id selected.

Table 2 plans also have an expiry_date and "active" field.

The plan should also not be valid if the expiry date is in the past or active is "0"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is this like a case study for us? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a **not** in Query, Where user does not exist in Table 2 with that plan id.

Suppose 
Table_1 -> Userid, Username 
Table_2 -> UserId, PlanId

```
SELECT UserId, Username FROM Table_1 
WHERE UserId NOT IN ( SELECT UserId FROM Table_2 WHERE PlanId = 1 )
```

This query will return all the users who are not linked with Plan 1.